# private class array adapter warning

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Can't seem to remove the warning from a class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText nameTxt, ageTxt, nationalityTxt, genderTxt, icnuTxt, dobTxt, pobTxt, heightTxt, weightTxt, bloodTypeTxt, bloodPressureTxt;
ArrayList<PatientDetails> Details = new ArrayList<PatientDetails>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    private class PatientDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PatientDetails>{
    public PatientDetailsAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.details_list, Details);


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details_list, parent, false);

        PatientDetails currentPatientDetails = Details.get(position);   

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientName);
        name.setText(currentPatientDetails.getName());

        TextView age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientAge);
        age.setText(currentPatientDetails.getAge());

        TextView icnu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientIcnu);
        icnu.setText(currentPatientDetails.getIcnu());

        TextView gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientGender);
        gender.setText(currentPatientDetails.getGender());

        TextView nationality = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientNationality);
        nationality.setText(currentPatientDetails.getNationality());

        TextView dob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientDob);
        dob.setText(currentPatientDetails.getDob());

        TextView pob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientPob);
        pob.setText(currentPatientDetails.getPob());

        TextView height = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientHeight);
        height.setText(currentPatientDetails.getHeight());

        TextView weight = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientWeight);
        weight.setText(currentPatientDetails.getWeight());

        TextView bloodType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientBloodType);
        bloodType.setText(currentPatientDetails.getBloodType());

        TextView bloodPressure = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientBloodPressure);
        bloodPressure.setText(currentPatientDetails.getBloodPressure());

        return view;




    }
}
```

It gives a yellow underline on **PatientDetailsAdapter** and says:

> the type MainActivity.PatientListAdapter is never used locally

I've added the public class activity as well as some for the private class
its an app program to add patient details and the list of details

Comment: did you creat an instance of the class? i get an error when i tried to creat a private class, because how do you use it, if its private.

Comment: a private class with public constructor?

Comment: post more code what you have tried....

Comment: Why are you making your class private?

Comment: if you are making it private, then you have to use inside MainActivity somehwere because you can't use outside. So it is saying that never used.

Comment: @donfuxx Yes even a private class needs a public constructor, else the hosting class (activity) won't be able to initialize the class...

Comment: @Lefteris according to this answer it does not need to be declared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243218/should-we-declare-a-public-constructor-when-the-class-is-declared-as-package-pri

Answer (score 0):

A private class, means it's only accessible by the class it is constructed in and not accessible by other classes.

You are getting a warning from the editor, because you have defined the class but it's never used.

If you use in your code the class, like

```
PatientDetailsAdapter myAdapter = new PatientDetailsAdapter();
```

You will see that you will not get the warning anymore.

Of course if you intent to use the ArrayAdapter from another class you should make it public.

Here is a sample skeleton of a proper adapter (to answer your other question) :

```
private class PatientDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PatientDetails> {

        public PatientDetailsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PatientDetails> array) {
            super(c, 0, array);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details_list, parent, false);

            PatientDetails currentPatientDetails = get(position);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientName);
            name.setText(currentPatientDetails.getName());

            TextView age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientAge);
            age.setText(currentPatientDetails.getAge());

            TextView icnu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientIcnu);
            icnu.setText(currentPatientDetails.getIcnu());

            TextView gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientGender);
            gender.setText(currentPatientDetails.getGender());

            TextView nationality = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientNationality);
            nationality.setText(currentPatientDetails.getNationality());

            TextView dob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientDob);
            dob.setText(currentPatientDetails.getDob());

            TextView pob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientPob);
            pob.setText(currentPatientDetails.getPob());

            TextView height = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientHeight);
            height.setText(currentPatientDetails.getHeight());

            TextView weight = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientWeight);
            weight.setText(currentPatientDetails.getWeight());

            TextView bloodType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientBloodType);
            bloodType.setText(currentPatientDetails.getBloodType());

            TextView bloodPressure = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patientBloodPressure);
            bloodPressure.setText(currentPatientDetails.getBloodPressure());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

And you initialize the adapter this way (after your Details ArrayList has items):

```
PatientDetailsAdapter myAdapter = new PatientDetailsAdapter(MainActivity.this, Details);
ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
mList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Once the adapter is initialized and set to the ListView then you will directly add/remove objects to the adapter and not the Details ArrayList, whenever you wish to change something in the ListView.

Like: `myAdapter.add(new PatientDetails(....));` or `myAdapter.remove((PatientDetails)object);`

And of course notifiy your ListView that the data has been changed by calling `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: there is no more warning howerever i am unable to run it.

Comment: This is another problem then. What do you mean you are unable to run it? The adapter needs to be passed the ArrayList to work.

Comment: got it. will try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PatientDetailsAdapter` class is certainly an inner class. Top level class can not be private. If you apply the keyword `private` to a top level class you will get a compilation error and not only warning.

Since you did not provide the whole class that contains your `PatientDetailsAdapter` I can only guess that the issue is that you do not explicitly use your class in your top level class or any other inner or nested classes of any level inside the top level class. This certainly will result a warning. (Note that the `private` scope does not limit access to your class from inside the top level class, even from other inner/nested classes. What is in the "source file" can see your `private` class/field/method... )

It may happen that  the warning is false in case you use the method via reflection. Since this is only a warning, what you should do is: ensure that your code is right and then ignore the warning. Or else understand where your code is wrong and fix it.